# How to lock Sql Server 2012 and Prevent Establishing Connection and perform Data migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In My University Management System i want to Perform Data Migration on Specific Day and so that i want close all open connections and Perform Data Migration as a Db admin user and after that Allow user to Establish connections to Database

after some Searching i find that script

`To Disable MultiUser`

```
 alter database dbName set single_user with rollback immediate
```

`To Enable MultiUser`

```
alter database dbName set multi_user with rollback immediate
```

**Question :**

how to Perform my required  Operation as a db admin?

it is a good way to do this or some better way ?

what does `Disable Script` doing?

what does `Enable Script` doing?

From this `Disable Script`all open connections will close ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you said is about the same what we do in this situation. The first statement puts the DB in "`single_user`" mode. That means, only YOUR current session is connected to the db after that statement. The "`with rollback immidiate`" option specifies that all open transaction and current queries and connections are closed and rolled back, so the database is in consistent state afterwards.

Personally, I dislike the "`single_user`" mode, because it allows any single user to connect if you accidentially close your connection. I'd use "`restricted_user`" instead. In that mode, only members of the db_owner fixed database role and dbcreator and sysadmin fixed server roles are allowed to connect to the database, but it does not limit their number. That will work better IF your users are not db_owner.

You second example just reverses that change and opens the DB to everyone ("`multi_user`") again.

Comment: thanks for you answer . did you recommend me to use `restricted_user` instead `single_user` ?...
is the bellow  syntax what you said right?
alter database dbName set restricted_user with rollback immediate